# Insert image at right of dropdown on Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a navbar in the top of the page, but i'm facing some problems:

After opening the navbar dropdown, I need to have a option list, and a image positioned to the right of the list. This image needs to have the same height of the list, just like in the following image (in portuguese, but easily understandable).

I achieved this setting a fixed height and width on the image, but the list can grow up and isn't a good option adjust it manually.

Another solution is to insert a div containing the list and the image, and set the image size to 100%, but when I do this, the dropdown isn't achieved anymore (I think i'm breaking the structure that Bootstrap uses to toggle the dropdown, am I right?).

How can I achieve this solution?

[image: estrutura]

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-elements">
                <li id="dropdown-produtos" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-uppercase top-text" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nossos Produtos<span class="caret top-caret"></span></a>
<!-- div was here --> <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-produtos">
                        <li class="dropdown-item-active">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu img-dropdown">
                                 <img src="assets/img.png"> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto4</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RealWorldCoder just removed it for a while, i'll add some CSS soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Elemento 1</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DropDown<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu another-class">
               <!-- ROW -->
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <!-- Column 1 -->
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <ul class="list-unstyled">
                         <li><a href="#">Texto 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Texto 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Texto 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Column 2 -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="drop-image">
                           <img src="./img/img.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Elemento 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Elemento 3</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Basically what I'm doing is create a div with a full width inside the dropdown element that comes as default in Boostrap. Inside this Full width row I create two columns with bootstrap col-md-6 class (you can do this with col-lg or col-sm or col-xs too) Inside this columns I add my content normally.

I created a class in the column 2 named "drop-image"; use this class to modify the img inside.

Hope it helps!

Btw, don't forget to style your dropdown (in the example I mark it with a class named *another-class*) so you define the position and width.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem, it's based off this plugin [Yamm3!](https://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/). See example Snippet.

Change this CSS rule if you need to make the dropdown wider because of the length of the link text. >

```
.list-unstyled, .list-unstyled ul {
    min-width: 180px
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  color: #666;
}
/* menu styes */

.list-unstyled,
.list-unstyled ul {
  min-width: 180px
}
.list-unstyled > li {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.list-unstyled > li > a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.yamm .nav,
.yamm .collapse,
.yamm .dropup,
.yamm .dropdown {
  position: static;
}
.yamm .container {
  position: relative;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.yamm .yamm-content {
  padding: 0 30px 10px 30px;
}
.yamm .yamm-content .nav-title {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .yamm-content .list-unstyled > li img {
    margin-top: -180px;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar yamm navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Grande Menu</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Classic list -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Nossos Produtos<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <!-- Content container to add padding -->
              <div class="yamm-content">
                <div class="row">
                  <h4 class="nav-title"><strong>A partida de um</strong></h4>

                  <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Vinculando um</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligando dois</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligação de três</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quatro ligação</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligação cinco</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seis ligação</a>

                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0/fff">
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Classic list -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Nossos Produtos Dois<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <!-- Content container to add padding -->
              <div class="yamm-content">
                <div class="row">
                  <h4 class="nav-title"><strong>A partida de um</strong></h4>

                  <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Vinculando um</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligando dois</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligação de três</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quatro ligação</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligação cinco</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seis ligação</a>

                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0/fff">
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-warning">Olá</div>
</div>
```